# Which file size is most accurate between ll, ls, and block size M or G?

Tags: linux, command-line, ls

So take the following dir:

```
      4096 dir1
7255937636 dir2
```

This is what I get with just an `ll` command. If I do `ls -l --block-size=M` I end up with:

```
   1M dir1
6920M dir2
```

Finally if I do `ls -l --block-size=G` I end up with:

```
1G dir1
7G dir2
```

I get that 6920 is easily rounded up to 7G but it seems like it's a big stretch to round that 4096 up to 1G. I also don't understand why the second example isn't 7256M or something more similar. Even more if we're always rounding up, why isn't the 7256 rounded up to 8G?

I guess I don't fully understand what it is I'm looking at here when nothing gives as accurate value as I'm thinking.

Comment: You're telling it to use block size of 1G, yet you're surprised that 4096 rounds up to 1G? It shows that there is something there, rather than the alternative which would suggest the dir was empty. 7256MB is less than 7GB = 7516192768Bytes,

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you are confusing the blocksize with the unit used for displaying the (correct) size. Try using

```
ls -lh
```

to enable auto scaling for human-readable output.

BTW: `ll` usually is just an alias for `ls -l`. This is also the most accurate value you will get.